# Django: open PDF file object

Tags: python, django

in my Django app I´m trying to open and show pdf files that wasn't loaded to a model, but can´t find the appropriate way.

I have a group of PDF invoices that I manually copied to `media/my_folder` (I use Dropbox as media host to be able to do that).

Then I want to show each invoice when requested.

**File object option**

After investigating several posts, I think the way to do it is creating a file object dynamically.

```
invoice_path = "my_folder/" + invoice_number + ".pdf"
f = open(invoice_path, 'w')
myfile = File(f)
```

Then I understand the in the template I could be able to access the file as it was loaded to the model.

```
<p><a href="{{ myfile.url }}" target="_blank">Ver factura AFIP</a></p>7
```

I get a FileNotFoundError, I guess I´m not setting the path to media files correctly.

> Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /catalog/perfilfactura/FA B
>   0003-00000220     Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'media/Facturas_Electronicas/FA-B-0003-00000220.pdf'

This happens when trying to `open` the file. The path I set it's supposed to be relative to MEDIA_ROOT, just add the subfolder "my_folder" and then the pdf file name.

**Path in template option**

I also tried to set the path directly in the template as in:

```
<p><a href="media/{{ archivo_factura }}.pdf" download>Ver factura AFIP</a></p>

<p><a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}Facturas_Electronicas/{{ archivo_factura }}.pdf" download>Ver factura AFIP</a></p>
```

In both cases I get a downloaded ampty PDFs.

My settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

And my Dropbox settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'my_token'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/Kinemed APP/'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the full error and traceback. Although I can't understand why you need a File object - or indeed why you need to open the file at all - rather than just passing the path.

Comment: Yes but when is that error happening? In the `open` line? And what is the actual full file path?

Comment: Updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to either open the file or create a File object. If your file is inside the media directory, all you need to do to create a URL for it is to join the media root:

```
invoice_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "my_folder/" + invoice_number + ".pdf")
```

and now pass `invoice_path` directly to the template and access it there.

Comment: Did it. If i print the path I can see the correct "/app/media/my_folder/FA-B-0003-00000211.pdf". In the template I just do: "<a href="{{ invoice_number }}">Ver factura AFIP</a>" and get a 404 Page not found error

Comment: I also get the 404 if I try: <a href="{{ invoice_number }}" download>Ver factura AFIP</a> or <a href="{{ invoice_number }}" target="_blank">Ver factura AFIP</a>

Comment: Have you configured anything to actually serve your media files from MEDIA_URL?

Comment: I added the settings to the post. It acutaly works I retrieve images from media with no problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If your media is on dropbox, how are you serving it from MEDIA_URL?

Comment: I just use {{ y.foto_2.url }} for files uploaded throught the app. Here you can see the images loading from Dropbox: https://afternoon-wildwood-39943.herokuapp.com/website/

Comment: But look none of this makes sense. If you are serving your uploaded files through Dropbox, **what is serving the files you are talking about here which are on your filesystem**?

Comment: I never mentioned my "filesystem". As explained in the post I want to be able to deliver this pdfs without uploading them through the app.